# R: How to create a table showing mean for one variable across groups

Tags: r, anova

I need to create a table showing the average *actions* across games in different divisions, from which I intend to run a one-way ANOVA test.

An example of my data is something like what is below although I am working with circa 5000 rows. How do I extract just the total actions as an average for each division into a table from which I can begin my statistical analysis? Thanks in advance

```
Division|V1|V2|Total Actions per game
--------|--|--|---------
1|n.a|n.a|20
1|n.a|n.a|24
2|n.a|n.a|50
3|n.a|n.a|43
2|n.a|n.a|45
5|n.a|n.a|80
1|n.a|n.a|34
4|n.a|n.a|36
3|n.a|n.a|27
1|n.a|n.a|46
4|n.a|n.a|41
'''
```

Comment: You should provide data in a useable format using `dput()`. For anova you would want the raw data, not a summary, but to get the average number of total actions for each division, look at the manual page for `?by` as in `by(Divisions, TotalActions, mean)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(Division) %>%
   summarise(actions = mean(`Total Actions per game`))
```

You can also use the base `by` function:

```
c(by(data$`Total Actions per game`, data$Division, mean))
```